# Can't hide InfoWindow on my marker

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

On my application I have few markers with a custom InfoWindow,

[image]

The blue marker is different, and when i click on it, i don't want the infowindow to popup.

So i tried use `marker.hideInfoWindow();` to hide the infowindow on my blue marker, but it doesn't seem to work, as i get the same InfoWindow that was on my screen last to popup one more time on the blue marker.

[image]

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
                View infoLayout=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custominfowindow, null);
                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                    if(marker.getTitle().equals("destAddr") || marker.getTitle().equals("myPos"))
                        {
                        // blue marker code executed here
                        marker.hideInfoWindow();
                        }
                    else
                    {
                    SearchUser su = new SearchUser();
                    Bitmap bm = null;
                    User user = su.getUserByName(marker.getTitle(), Users);
                    if(user!=null)
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(user.getImagePath());

                    ImageView infoImg = (ImageView) infoLayout.findViewById(R.id.infoImg);
                    TextView infoName = (TextView) infoLayout.findViewById(R.id.infoName);
                    RatingBar infoRat = (RatingBar) infoLayout.findViewById(R.id.infoRat);

                    infoName.setText( user.getName() );
                    infoRat.setRating((float)user.getRating());                 
                    infoImg.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    }
                    return infoLayout;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Your really close on this.  Like the custom infoWindow.  Hope you like my code below.  With it you could make the infoWindow come alive and actually make the rating control work on the map.

Answer (score 0):

override onMarkerClick and if you don't want the info window to show return true.

Simple way is to examine the title or snippet in the marker in onMarkerCLick

```
private void setUpMap() {

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);

...

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    return (marker.getTitle()=="Blue")?true:false;
}
```

A more complex method that could determine the actual blue/read icon would use Marker.getId() in the onMarkerClick() method.  When you add a marker to the map save the markerId in a list or something.  Below I'm adding a marker to the map in asynctask publishProgress and saving the markerId. You can't extend final class markerOptions to add a markerId field so simply make a bean.

```
public class KmlMarkerOptions {

public MarkerOptions markeroptions = new MarkerOptions();
public String id = "";

public KmlMarkerOptions(){

}
}
```

When adding the marker to the map save the id in the collection of beans for MarkerOptions.  Below example uses publish progress of asynctask but you can do this anywhere in your code.

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(KmlMarkerOptions... params) {
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(params[0].markeroptions);
    params[0].id = marker.getId();
}
```

Now when the marker is clicked locate the original markerOptions from the id in marker and determine what kind of marker is being clicked.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    return showMarker(marker);
}


private boolean showMarker(Marker marker) {
    KmlMarkerOptions kmlmo = findKmlMarkerOptions(marker);
    if (kmlmo != null) {
        // here you could check the type of icon blue/red
        // return (kmlmo.markerOptions.icon== blah)?true:false;
        // what I'm doing is showing a dialog fragment with all
        // kinds of goodies like buttons and active web content 
        // right over the map like a custominfowindow should be.
        // and also moving the map centered on the marker.
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            KmlMarkerDialogFragment markerWebView = KmlMarkerDialogFragment
                    .newInstance(kmlmo);
            markerWebView.show(fm, "fragment_marker");
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newLatLng(kmlmo.markeroptions.getPosition()));
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public KmlMarkerOptions findKmlMarkerOptions(Marker marker) {
    if (_kmlmo != null) {
        String id = marker.getId();
        for (KmlMarkerOptions mo : _kmlmo) {
            if (id.equals(mo.id)) {
                return mo;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

*// one click ahead of the competition because with this code you can show a truly custom infowindow with active buttons and you could make the rating stars actually process and access web content whatever you want to do*